# How to draw a drag and droppable line on an image?

Tags: python, opencv, mouseevent

Suppose I draw a straight line on the following image, using

```py
img = cv2.line(img, (0, 20), (400, 20), (0, 0, 255), 9)
```

[image]

Now, if I want to move the red line on the image (drag and droppable) by using a mouse event – is that possible?  If so, please share your idea.

Comment: It’s probably possible, but IMHO I can’t help feeling it’s not the right tool. What’s the bigger picture - what are you trying to do?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am working on an OCR related Project. Where I need to identify the column on the PDF file. Sometimes the project doesn't meet the requirement. That's why I need to manually select the column. by Drag and Dropping the line.

Comment: Please be more specific. You want the user to be able to identify an area with the mouse, yes? Is that area one row of pixels? One column of pixels? The entire width/height of the image? Or is it a rectangular area? If rectangular, could it be defined by mouse-clicking top-left and bottom-right corners? Could there be multiple areas needing to be defined?

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to rotate the line by grabbing and raising one end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced your line by some rectangle with height `9`, that makes things easier.

Inside the callback, check whether the left mouse button was clicked inside the rectangle. If so, save the mouse position w.r.t. the "line", and set some flag to indicate "dragging" is active. While moving the mouse, re-draw the line w.r.t. the saved mouse position. If the left mouse button was released, unset the flag for the "dragging".

Here's some code:

```py
import cv2


# Actual mouse callback function
def move_line(event, x, y, flags, param):

    # Controls and image need to be global
    global diff, img, hold, l, t

    # Left mouse button down: Save mouse position where line was dragged
    if (event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) and \
            (x >= l) and \
            (x <= l + 400) and \
            (y >= t) and \
            (y <= t + 9):
        diff = (x - l, y - t)
        hold = True

    # Left mouse button up: Stop dragging
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        hold = False

    # During dragging: Update line w.r.t. mouse position; show image
    if hold:
        l, t = (x - diff[0], y - diff[1])
        img_copy = img.copy()
        cv2.rectangle(img_copy, (l, t), (l + 400, t + 9), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.imshow('image', img_copy)


# Initialize controls
diff = (0, 0)
hold = False
l, t = (0, 100)

# Set up some image; work on copy
img = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')
img_copy = img.copy()

# Initalize line; show image
cv2.rectangle(img_copy, (l, t), (l + 400, t + 9), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
cv2.imshow('image', img_copy)
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', move_line)

# Loop until the 'c' key is pressed
while True:

    # Wait for keypress
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # If 'c' key is pressed, break from loop
    if key == ord('c'):
        break
```

Using a rectangle has the advantage, that you can easily capture regions of interest (ROIs) from your image, which you then can feed to OCR for example (looking at the comments).

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks - as always! :-)

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is used to process and analyze images.

What you are looking for is a computer graphics functionality in which you can manipulate the image freely. This is more of [OpenGL's](https://www.opengl.org//) area instead of OpenCV.